# Insert Into using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am tryng to insert a new user into a simple table that contains ID and Name.

This is the query that I execute:

```
INSERT INTO [dKArchive].[dbo].[Logins]
       ([IDL]
       ,[Name])
 VALUES
       (37
       ,'pippo.paperino')
GO
```

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

After executing query, the value is added in the table, after when I close the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and reopen it, this data disappears.

Why does it happen?

Thanks. Best regards.

Comment: Where are you looking when you say that the data disappears? Disappeared from where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second attempt at answering:

SSMS has an option to set that every query is a transaction. You find this under

```
Tools...->Options->Query Execution->SQL Server->ANSI->SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTION
```

If this option is on, you will get something close to the behaviour you describe.  However, when closing SSMS, you will get a warning about uncommitted transactions.  **Ignoring this warning is not a good idea.**

At that time, you can click Commit and all is well, *or* you can just turn off this option.

Comment: I try to use begin transaction  and commit at the end.  Not work.

Comment: As suggested by Stig Hemmer, make the IMPLICIT_TRANSACTION option off. if this option is on, even you create a transaction and commit it, it will not work.

Comment: Thank Stig and Ramesh for your collaboration.